# Modify Ransack not_in query to include when field is nil

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arel, ransack

I am querying my model like so:

`MyModel.search(year_not_in: [2000, 2010, 2015])`

But am getting back results from `MyModel` ONLY where `year` is not `nil`. For example, the query hits where `MyModel.year = 1999` but not where `MyModel.year = nil`. I expect `nil` to not be in that array but perhaps that is how it's defined in SQL.

Is there a way I can override the `year` or `year_not_in` ransacker to add the condition above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this without overriding, though I would still be interested in how to do that. Joining statements like so was my solution:

`.search(m: 'or', year_not_in: [2000, 2010, 2015], year_null: true)`

Answer (score 0):

First of all :  this solution test with `ransack (2.4.2)` and `rails 6.1.3`
To achieve this, GEM ransack give us a solution is to add a new predicate :

If you'd like to add your own custom Ransack predicates

> not_in_or_null

You can do it like this way :

**"config/initializers/ransack.rb"**

You add this

```
Ransack.configure do |config|
  config.add_predicate 'not_in_or_null', arel_predicate: 'not_in_or_null'
end

module Arel
  module Predications
    def not_in_or_null(other)
      left = not_in(other)
      right = eq(nil)
      left.or(right)
    end
  end
end
```

And than, you have a new predicate now.